# Curvature proof of a convex plane curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

Having a little trouble with part b. 
Is there a way to show that this curve would be arc length paramaterized? I am assuming that we cannot say this. 
If it is not we can take alpha', alpha'' and then compute curvature through 
|alpha' x alpha"|/ |alpha'|^3
This is the brute force method to solve this problem, which is very messy. However, I am assuming that there is another way to solve this problem, but I seem to be missing a theorem that could push me in the right direction. Any hints? Thank you! 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you shouldn't be posting my textbook on here without permission. (You seem to be pasting in a number of exercises from it. Please stop.) Although you can use the formula you cited, you can also just use the usual chain rule computation to adjust for non-arclength-parametrized curves. The crucial thing to think about is what the unit tangent vector $\mathbf T(\theta)$ is.

Comment: Thank you. A friend told me about your online text and I am self studying DiffGeo and trying to learn from your exercises. Is there a place where I can check my solutions from your problems

Comment: Sadly, no. Having solutions widely available (even here) makes it tough for those of us who teach courses with graded homework out of the text. On the other hand, I will be happy to give you occasional hints on here or to criticize solutions you want to type up in appropriate format here.

Comment: Gotcha, I really like your text and apologize for posting the problems I was having trouble solving. I'll let you know if I have a question to a problem. I will type it up next time! Thanks! Great text to learn from

Comment: Thanks. At some point you should accept answers when you're satisfied. If you want to wait until you've posted your solution (or an outline of it) as an edit to your question, I'll be glad to edit my answer responding to it.

Comment: could I please have a small hint on the relation between α(θ) and p(θ) at 0 or 2pi to show that 
p''(2pi) - p''(0) = 0 
Thank you!

Comment: Oh, $\alpha$ and $p$ are periodic with period $2\pi$ (e.g., because the curve is smooth).

Comment: But how will that relate to p'? Will that still hold true for p'?

Comment: Differentiate $p(\theta+2\pi)=p(\theta)$.

Comment: Cool! That works, but I just have a question on why we can just say that p(θ+2π)=p(θ) since it is the tangent line. Do we have to say something about α(θ+2π)=α(θ) and that relating to p?

Comment: Is it just the tangent line is periodic as well?